# How to replace INHERIT command in postges?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm looking at an open source project that runs on postgres. However I am hoping to get it to work on a different postgres based database called yugabyte.

While running the open source project it complained to me as follows:

```
psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: INHERITS not supported yet
LINE 9: CREATE TABLE ir_act_window (primary key(id)) INHERITS (ir_ac...
```

So it seams yugabytedb does not support `INHERTS`. Digging deeper into the docs of what exactly it does https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-inherit.html, the table created basically will have all the attributes of where it's inhertting from. However since I can't use the `INHERIT` command I'm wondering if there is an alternative way that I can achieve the same thing? Below is the original SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE ir_actions (
  id serial,
  primary key(id)
);
CREATE TABLE ir_act_window (primary key(id)) INHERITS (ir_actions);
CREATE TABLE ir_act_report_xml (primary key(id)) INHERITS (ir_actions);
CREATE TABLE ir_act_url (primary key(id)) INHERITS (ir_actions);
CREATE TABLE ir_act_server (primary key(id)) INHERITS (ir_actions);
CREATE TABLE ir_act_client (primary key(id)) INHERITS (ir_actions);
```

Should I just create a brand new table from scratch instead, since it's a simple table? ie:

```
CREATE TABLE ir_act_window (
    id serial,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really replace table inheritance: how would you make a query on the parent table to return values from all inheritance children?

You'd have to study the code and figure out why they use inheritance. Perhaps you can modify the code so that it doesn't need table inheritance, but the changes will probably not be trivial.